# Ceiling Fan Operation

Tags: electrical

I have a dimmable single switch for a ceiling chandelier.  I will replace it with a ceiling fan with light.  I still want to use the wall dimmable switch when I turn on the light.  I expect the ceiling fan to light up but not the fan unless I pull the chain down.  In other words, I understand that I can wire the ceiling fan to the wall, but only the fan will come on if I yank the chain down once to turn on the fan, and down again to turn off.  Is this correct?  So chain turns the fan on and off, that is it.  Please advise, and thank you.

Comment: it depends on the fan and home wiring, but you can typically have either or both switched at the wall.

Comment: It'll help if you add the exact model (and manufacturer) of ceiling fan!

Answer (score 1):

Whether this will work or not depends on the wiring. If power goes to the light first and then to the switch (switch loop) then this should be easy. However, if power goes to the switch and then to the light, you can't do this unless you have an additional wire because the fan can't be on a dimmer switch. No way to know what you've got without opening the switch box.

There is also the possibility of a fan/light with a wireless remote. They are very common now but a lot of people prefer traditional switches.